# Getting my Ubuntu 23.04 install to run full-screen on Hyper-V

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, xrdp

I've installed the Lunar Lobster build as a VM in Hyper-V.  I'm stuck in 1024x768.
I'd like to be able to do the full-screen option that Microsoft gives in their quick installs that uses XRDP and has always matched the resolution of my desktop (in this case 2560x1440).

I've tried a few options:
I've installed xrdp, xfce4 and xorgxrdp
I've used various setup scripts that have made changes to ~/.xsession and grub to no avail (like this one: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18725 )
I've tried just upping the default screen resolution with some tools like xrandr and hit failures like; "Failed to get gamma size for default output".
Firewall is disabled.
I'm trying to walk through the differences between the setup Microsoft uses on a quick create image vs. a stock image from Ubuntu, but it's a bit tedious.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Linux usage questions should be posted to [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su] instead.